# Setting guessing level in linear mixed modelling in R

Tags: r, mixed-model

This is more of a conceptual question so I won't post any examples. I want to predict accuracy from reaction time in a mixed model setting. The problem is that the guessing level in accuracy was 0.5, and when I model the data the usual way I get predicted values which go below 0.5 which doesn't make sense for my data. Is there a way how I could model the guessing probability of 0.5? So far I was using the lme4 package...

Thank you!

edit: Basically we had a two-choice task (people saw some stimuli they have learned before, alongside distractors and had to answer whether the stimuli is familiar-right button- or unfamiliar - left button). Therefore, the lower asymptote of the speed-accuracy curve should be by 0.5 and not by 0. The lower level units are trials within a person, and the higher level units are persons. So we have a within-person and between-person variance which makes it a mixed model.

Comment: I don't this can be answered without some background and details of the mixed model.

Comment: I hope that the edit is detailed enough ;)